# How to use the debugging tool in Spyder for python scripts?

Tags: python, debugging, editor, spyder

I was recently introduced to Spyder. I decided to use Spyder because of its debugging capabilities. However, I have not been able to effectively use pdb in Spyder. When I started, I had the impression that the debugging tool would be similar to that of MATLAB. Is this true? How can the interpreter point to the breakpoint? I'd appreciate a proper resource on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) If you are using an Spyder version less than **2.2.5**, please update it. On it you will find a **Debug** menu from which you can set breakpoints and control all debugging actions we have to offer.

Comment: Is there a way to step out of a function once you have stepped in and want to pop out, in Spyder?

Comment: There is a button in the Debug toolbar (the blue buttons next to the Run ones) whose tooltip says: *Run until current function or method returns*. The form of the button is an arrow coming out of two spaced dots.